# How to set default (or change) meta description in include file

Tags: php, metadata

i have webpage example.org, where i have multiple subcategories like:

- index.php?page=login
- index.php?page=category
- page=login?page=names

and i have included in index.php the head.php file which contain:

```
if(!empty($settings->meta_description) && (!isset($_GET['page']) || (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != 'category')))
    echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $settings->meta_description . '" />';
elseif(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'category' && !empty($category->description))
    echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $category->description . '" />';
```

Is it possible to set default meta description for all pages (subcategories)? Or how to manual write description to all pages (its about 25 pages, so i can do it manual, but how?)

Because user can add pages, so i need to set default meta description (because i dont want duplicate metadescription)

Have anyone solution? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Think simply a final `else` block with your default no? Most people probably are using some sort of framework for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, the best way to do this would be to set up a database table with a `name` column and a `description` column. Then you could check each page's description like this *(this example uses `mysql` syntax)*:

```
$result = $mysql->query("SELECT description FROM pageinfo WHERE page = '" 
    . $mysql->escape_string($_GET['page']) . "'");
if($result->num_rows){
    $description = $result->fetch_array()[0];
} else {
    $description = 'Default description...';
}
#echo the description here...
```

However, if you don't want to use a database or don't want to learn the syntax, you could do it with pure PHP:

You could use a switch block to check which page you are on, and then set the description based on the page (`$desc` will be the page's description in this example).

```
#use a switch block to check what page the user is on
$desc = '';
switch($_GET['page']){
    case 'login':
        $desc = 'Login page description';
        break; #make sure you include the break statement
    case 'category':
        $desc = 'Category description';
        break;

    #( include the rest of the page names )

    default:
        #this will happen if none of the other conditions are met
        $desc = 'Default description';
        break;
}
```

Here's some information on a `switch block` from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece of code depending on which value it equals to.

Comment: I use your code and its showing this when i debug it: <meta name="description" content="" /> - i change the code, but i dont know why this: switch($_GET['page']){ -> not work.. because its always take data from $desc = ""; as you can see

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me - can you comment with all your code?

Comment: Ok now its work fine, i have to add <meta description.../> after the switch code :D fail. sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sort of reinventing the wheel, but for learning purposes, does the following make sense to you? Honestly you should probably take a look at how a few MVC frameworks handle this.

```
<?php
$pageData = [
    'category'  => ['title' => 'This is a title', 'description' => 'Hello world...'],
    'login'     => ['title' => 'This is a title', 'description' => 'Hello world...'],
    'names'     => ['title' => 'This is a title', 'description' => 'Hello world...'],
]


if (isset($_GET['page']) {
    if (isset($pageData[$_GET['page'])) {   
        //we have defined meta data specific for this page                  
        echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $pageData[$_GET['page']['description'] . '" />';            
    } else {
        //page paramter was passsed but no specific values assigned for the page
        echo '<meta name="description" content="This is some default/fallback text." />';
    }
} else {
    //page paramter not passsed in
    echo '<meta name="description" content="This is some other default/fallback text." />';
}
```